# How to specifically display certain columns in nth-child?

Tags: css, media

I have this css code that I've tried from another website:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
#data tr > * {display: none}
#data tr > *:nth-child(12) ~ * {display: table-cell}
}
```

But this code displays only the 13th column and the others and hides the column[1-12]. How do display specific columns when I access my webpage in mobile? For example, I want to display only 4 columns when in mobile: columns(1,28,29,97). Is there any way to display column(1,28,29,97) specifically?

Comment: Could you not just add a class to the columns which you want to display for mobile then reference them in your media queries `display: block` for that class?

Comment: hmm about my table sir, It creates th and td when button_click event() is fired. so when I pressed the click event it will create th and td inside the table

Comment: Can't you add the class to your tds after the event, perhaps count the tds and add for 1,28,29,97

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something similar to this:

https://jsfiddle.net/h9z6hLjv/

Just add the class `showMob` to the columns you want to display for mobile. Resize the window to see the media query take effect.